# How to fast get the SVD of $A-xx^T$ based on the SVD results of $A$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, svd

In the question, $A\in R^{d\times d}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, $x\in R^{d}$ is a vector, and SVD means Singular Value Decomposition.

This question seems to be related with 'Rank-One Modification of the Symmetric Eigenproblem'. The application of this question includes PCA for uncentered data https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5823v5.pdf .

Comment: It can be done in $O(n^2 \log^2 n)$, see for example (https://www.zarm.uni-bremen.de/gamm2008/files/upfiles/stange_paper_proceeding_stange.pdf) this is not unlike the problem of up/downdating the Cholesky factorization which similarly, can be done in $O(n^2)$ (http://perso.uclouvain.be/paul.vandooren/publications/BojanczykBVD87.pdf). I think (http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0895479893251472) may also be of related interest.